# How to check if event target is contained within an element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-delegation

I am trying to apply event delegation and so I want to update the text when I click within the li element but when I click inside a element, it won't fire. I don't want to attach the event listener directly to li as the list can be updated and there can be any element type within li.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const textField = document.querySelector('p');

menu.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    textField.textContent = e.target.textContent;
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a>About us</a></li>
  </ul>

  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the li and not the anchor or any other child element, use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```
const li = e.target.closest("li");
if (li) { /* do whatever */ }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. In my case I just traversed up the DOM using a while loop. But using what javascript already has is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the bubbling effect by attaching a `click` event listener to the parent list, `ul`.

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const ul = menu.querySelector('ul');
const textField = document.querySelector('p');

ul.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target != ul) textField.textContent = e.target.textContent;
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a>About us</a></li>
  </ul>

  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This can cause problem if there is padding to `ul` or the `div`.